# Static linking, visual studio, and FLANN

Tags: visual-studio-2010, linker, compiler-errors, static-libraries, hdf5

I am trying to compile FLANN_Example.cpp in Visual Studio 2010.  The file is a usage example of the `Fast Library for Approximate Nearest Neighbors` ([FLANN](http://www.cs.ubc.ca/~mariusm/index.php/FLANN/FLANN)); it is intended to produce an executable. I went through the whole `CMake` routine and installed the HD5F library (a dependency) set up for static linking.

I can compile every thing else - except for flann_example.cpp.

Here is the output:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: ZERO_CHECK, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
2>------ Build started: Project: flann_cpp_s, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
2>MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll) : error LNK2005: _malloc already defined in LIBCMTD.lib(dbgmalloc.obj)
2>MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll) : error LNK2005: _memmove already defined in LIBCMTD.lib(memmove.obj)
2>MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll) : error LNK2005: _free already defined in LIBCMTD.lib(dbgfree.obj)
2>MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll) : error LNK2005: _fclose already defined in LIBCMTD.lib(fclose.obj)
2>MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll) : error LNK2005: _fprintf already defined in LIBCMTD.lib(fprintf.obj)
2>MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll) : error LNK2005: ___iob_func already defined in LIBCMTD.lib(_file.obj)
2>MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll) : error LNK2005: _sprintf already defined in LIBCMTD.lib(sprintf.obj)
2>MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll) : error LNK2005: _setvbuf already defined in LIBCMTD.lib(setvbuf.obj)
2>MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll) : error LNK2005: _strtol already defined in LIBCMTD.lib(strtol.obj)
2>MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll) : error LNK2005: _isdigit already defined in LIBCMTD.lib(_ctype.obj)
2>MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll) : error LNK2005: _isalpha already defined in LIBCMTD.lib(_ctype.obj)
2>MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll) : error LNK2005: _abort already defined in LIBCMTD.lib(abort.obj)
2>MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll) : error LNK2005: _strncmp already defined in LIBCMTD.lib(strncmp.obj)
2>MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll) : error LNK2005: _fopen already defined in LIBCMTD.lib(fopen.obj)
2>MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll) : error LNK2005: _isspace already defined in LIBCMTD.lib(_ctype.obj)
2>MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll) : error LNK2005: __errno already defined in LIBCMTD.lib(dosmap.obj)
2>MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll) : error LNK2005: _strrchr already defined in LIBCMTD.lib(strrchr.obj)
2>MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll) : error LNK2005: _isalnum already defined in LIBCMTD.lib(_ctype.obj)
2>MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll) : error LNK2005: _strcspn already defined in LIBCMTD.lib(strcspn.obj)
2>MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll) : error LNK2005: __read already defined in LIBCMTD.lib(read.obj)
2>MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll) : error LNK2005: __get_osfhandle already defined in LIBCMTD.lib(osfinfo.obj)
2>MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll) : error LNK2005: __open already defined in LIBCMTD.lib(open.obj)
2>MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll) : error LNK2005: __write already defined in LIBCMTD.lib(write.obj)
2>MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll) : error LNK2005: __lseeki64 already defined in LIBCMTD.lib(lseeki64.obj)
2>MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll) : error LNK2005: __chsize_s already defined in LIBCMTD.lib(chsize.obj)
2>MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll) : error LNK2005: __close already defined in LIBCMTD.lib(close.obj)
2>MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll) : error LNK2005: __fileno already defined in LIBCMTD.lib(fileno.obj)
2>MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll) : error LNK2005: _fread already defined in LIBCMTD.lib(fread.obj)
2>MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll) : error LNK2005: _fwrite already defined in LIBCMTD.lib(fwrite.obj)
2>MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll) : error LNK2005: _fflush already defined in LIBCMTD.lib(fflush.obj)
2>MSVCRT.lib(ti_inst.obj) : error LNK2005: "private: __thiscall type_info::type_info(class type_info const &)" (??0type_info@@AAE@ABV0@@Z) already defined in LIBCMTD.lib(typinfo.obj)
2>MSVCRT.lib(ti_inst.obj) : error LNK2005: "private: class type_info & __thiscall type_info::operator=(class type_info const &)" (??4type_info@@AAEAAV0@ABV0@@Z) already defined in LIBCMTD.lib(typinfo.obj)
2>LINK : warning LNK4098: defaultlib 'MSVCRT' conflicts with use of other libs; use /NODEFAULTLIB:library
2>C:\flann-1.6.11-src\bin\lib\Debug\flann_example.exe : fatal error LNK1169: one or more multiply defined symbols found
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Here are my **Additional Include Directories**:

```
C:\Program Files %28x86%29\HDF Group\HDF5\1.8.7\include\cpp;
C:/flann-1.6.11-src/src/cpp;
%(AdditionalIncludeDirectories)
```

Here are my **Additional Dependencies** under **Linker**:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\HDF Group\HDF5\1.8.7\lib\hdf5_cpp.lib;
C:\Program Files (x86)\HDF Group\HDF5\1.8.7\lib\hdf5.lib;
C:\Program Files (x86)\HDF Group\HDF5\1.8.7\lib\hdf5_hl_cpp.lib;
C:\Program Files (x86)\HDF Group\HDF5\1.8.7\lib\hdf5_hl.lib;
C:\Program Files (x86)\HDF Group\HDF5\1.8.7\lib\tools\hdf5_tools.lib;
C:\Program Files (x86)\HDF Group\HDF5\1.8.7\lib\zlib.lib;
C:\Program Files (x86)\HDF Group\HDF5\1.8.7\lib\libszip.lib;
C:\flann-1.6.11-src\bin\lib\Debug\flann_cpp_s.lib;
C:\flann-1.6.11-src\bin\lib\Debug\flann_s.lib;
C:\flann-1.6.11-src\bin\lib\Debug\flann_cpp-gd.lib;
C:\flann-1.6.11-src\bin\lib\Debug\flann.lib;
C:\flann-1.6.11-src\bin\lib\Debug\flann_cpp_s-gd.lib;
C:\flann-1.6.11-src\bin\lib\Debug\flann_cpp.lib;%(AdditionalDependencies)
```

**Compiler Options**:

> /I"C:\Program Files (x86)\HDF Group\HDF5\1.8.7\include\cpp"
>   /I"C:/flann-1.6.11-    src/src/cpp" /Zi /nologo /W3 /WX- /Od /Ob0 /Oy-
>   /D "WIN32" /D "_WINDOWS" /D "_DEBUG" /D "_FLANN_VERSION=1.6.11" /D
>   "FLANN_STATIC" /D "CMAKE_INTDIR=\"Debug\"" /D "_MBCS" /Gm- /EHsc /RTC1
>   /MTd /GS /fp:precise /Zc:wchar_t /Zc:forScope /GR
>   /Fp"flann_cpp_s.dir\Debug\flann_example.pch" /Fa"Debug"
>   /Fo"flann_cpp_s.dir\Debug\"
>   /Fd"C:/flann-1.6.11-src/bin/lib/Debug/flann_cpp_s.pdb" /Gd /TP
>   /analyze- /errorReport:queue

Some help would be really appreciated! I have spent an inordinate amount of time on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be yet another case of 'Make sure you are compiling everything statically'